# Kibana installation error "Kibana server is not ready yet" (CentOS)

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Working on a Kibana deployment, after installing Kibana & Elasticsearch i get the error 'Kibana server is not ready yet'.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-elasticsearch-logstash-and-kibana-elastic-stack-on-centos-7

```
[opc@homer7 etc]$
[opc@homer7 etc]$ sudo systemctl status kibana
● kibana.service - Kibana
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kibana.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2021-02-26 13:56:07 CET; 37s ago
     Docs: https://www.elastic.co
 Main PID: 18215 (node)
   Memory: 208.3M
   CGroup: /system.slice/kibana.service
           └─18215 /usr/share/kibana/bin/../node/bin/node /usr/share/kibana/bin/../src/cli/dist --logging.dest="/var/log/kibana/kibana.log" --pid.file="/run/kibana/kibana.pid"

Feb 26 13:56:07 homer7 systemd[1]: kibana.service failed.
Feb 26 13:56:07 homer7 systemd[1]: Started Kibana.
[opc@homer7 etc]$
[opc@homer7 etc]$
[opc@homer7 etc]$
[opc@homer7 etc]$ sudo journalctl --unit kibana
-- Logs begin at Fri 2021-02-26 11:31:02 CET, end at Fri 2021-02-26 13:56:57 CET. --
Feb 26 12:15:38 homer7 systemd[1]: Started Kibana.
Feb 26 13:21:25 homer7 systemd[1]: Stopping Kibana...
Feb 26 13:22:55 homer7 systemd[1]: kibana.service stop-sigterm timed out. Killing.
Feb 26 13:22:55 homer7 systemd[1]: kibana.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Feb 26 13:22:55 homer7 systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana.
Feb 26 13:22:55 homer7 systemd[1]: Unit kibana.service entered failed state.
Feb 26 13:22:55 homer7 systemd[1]: kibana.service failed.
Feb 26 13:25:05 homer7 systemd[1]: Started Kibana.
Feb 26 13:25:29 homer7 systemd[1]: Stopping Kibana...
Feb 26 13:26:59 homer7 systemd[1]: kibana.service stop-sigterm timed out. Killing.
Feb 26 13:26:59 homer7 systemd[1]: kibana.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Feb 26 13:26:59 homer7 systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana.
Feb 26 13:26:59 homer7 systemd[1]: Unit kibana.service entered failed state.
Feb 26 13:26:59 homer7 systemd[1]: kibana.service failed.
Feb 26 13:27:56 homer7 systemd[1]: Started Kibana.
Feb 26 13:40:53 homer7 systemd[1]: Stopping Kibana...
Feb 26 13:42:23 homer7 systemd[1]: kibana.service stop-sigterm timed out. Killing.
Feb 26 13:42:23 homer7 systemd[1]: kibana.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Feb 26 13:42:23 homer7 systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana.
Feb 26 13:42:23 homer7 systemd[1]: Unit kibana.service entered failed state.
Feb 26 13:42:23 homer7 systemd[1]: kibana.service failed.
Feb 26 13:42:23 homer7 systemd[1]: Started Kibana.
Feb 26 13:44:09 homer7 systemd[1]: Stopping Kibana...
Feb 26 13:45:40 homer7 systemd[1]: kibana.service stop-sigterm timed out. Killing.
Feb 26 13:45:40 homer7 systemd[1]: kibana.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Feb 26 13:45:40 homer7 systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana.
Feb 26 13:45:40 homer7 systemd[1]: Unit kibana.service entered failed state.
Feb 26 13:45:40 homer7 systemd[1]: kibana.service failed.
Feb 26 13:45:40 homer7 systemd[1]: Started Kibana.
Feb 26 13:54:37 homer7 systemd[1]: Stopping Kibana...
Feb 26 13:56:07 homer7 systemd[1]: kibana.service stop-sigterm timed out. Killing.
Feb 26 13:56:07 homer7 systemd[1]: kibana.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=9/KILL
Feb 26 13:56:07 homer7 systemd[1]: Stopped Kibana.
Feb 26 13:56:07 homer7 systemd[1]: Unit kibana.service entered failed state.
Feb 26 13:56:07 homer7 systemd[1]: kibana.service failed.
Feb 26 13:56:07 homer7 systemd[1]: Started Kibana.
[opc@homer7 etc]$
[opc@homer7 etc]$
```

Comment: Hello Marty. You should look directly to kibana logs where you can find more info. Is elasticsearch really up and running?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe The issue happened due to kibana was unable to access elasticsearch locally.

I think that you have enabled xpack.security plugin for security purpose at elasticsearch.yml by adding a new line :

```
xpack.security.enabled : true
```

if so you need to uncomment the two lines on kibana.yml :

#elasticsearch.username: "kibana"

#elasticsearch.password: "pass"

```
elasticsearch.username = "kibana_system" 
elasticsearch.password = "your-password"
```

after saving the changes, restart kibana service :

```
sudo sservice kibana restart
```

Answer (score 0):

check `$systemctl status elasticsearch`. I am guessing your elasticsearch service is not started yet.

Comment: This is probably not the case , maybe elastic server is up and run and Kibana couldn't configured the server yet .

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are many factors that need to be checked, first of all please go to the config directory of where you installed Kibana and check the `kibana.yml` by `sudo vi kibana.yml` and check the port of elastic server that Kibana tries to connect(the default is 9200).
[Here](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/master/config/kibana.yml) is an example of default configuration.

After matching this configuration with your need go to the script file that you save in for Kibana service and check the the `[unix]` part to if it needs activate elastic service first and if you didn't add "Required" part for Elasticserver  make sure that the elastic server is up and run before running Kibana as service, you can also lunch Kibana as shell by going to the bin director of Kibana and lunching Kibana .

Answer (score 0):

you can check

systemctl status kibana -l
cat /var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log | grep -i -E "error|warn"

after

systemctl restart elasticsearch

You can try again.